# SonarQube ant runner fails with java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube

I'm upgrading **SonarQube** from the previous **LTS release** to the most recent one.
I learned that the ant configuration changed, especially regarding binary/library paths.

For one of our (multi-module) projects, I am defining the following property:

```
<property name="myproject.sonar.java.libraries" value="${general-classpath},addons/myproject/lib/*.jar" />
```

The ant property `${general-classpath}` is a comma separated converted , each element pointing to a specific jar.

When running sonar, it fails with an `IllegalStateException`:

```
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:53)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:48)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching 'addons/myproject/lib/*.jar'
        at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.getFilesFromProperty(JavaClasspath.java:143)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:92)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.getElements(JavaClasspath.java:221)
        at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:92)
        at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.<init>(VisitorsBridge.java:85)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.<init>(JavaSquid.java:85)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:91)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 24 more
```

My guess is that SonarQube that the last element in the defined `sonar.java.libraries` property causes this: `addons/myproject/lib/*.jar`

**Jarfiles which match this pattern do definitely exist.**
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove ".jar" at the end and it should work. Indeed, for some unknown reasons, SonarSource does not want to update the documentation at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin. See http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Very-misleading-documentation-of-sonar-java-binaries-and-sonar-java-libraries-td5031803.html.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll try that. However, the referenced issue https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-160 definitely lists *.jar as a valid pattern. So this seems to be not (only) a documentation bug but also an implementation bug. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, your hint did not help. Same exception is thrown in this case.

Comment: @David, I am going to answer you on mailing list but your statements are wrong.

Comment: Are you sure about the path? Did you try `**/addons/myproject/lib/*` ?